# BLDC back-emf measurement

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, back-emf

I am trying to make a sensorless control system for a BLDC, using "Trapezoidal control", see here:

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprabz3/sprabz3.pdf?ts=1610192643720&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

The schematic looks like this,

[image]

PWM is applied on the top transistors during a commutation, while lower transistors are ON during the whole commutation.

Anyways, I need to measure the back-emf of the BLDC. In this document on page 2,

https://www.cypress.com/file/71631/download

one can read that the back-emf can be measured by measuring the non-energized phase. 3Ec = 2Vc. But when I measure this on the oscilloscope it doesn't really look like anything I can use.

I am measuring directly on one of the phases. During time period 1, the lower transistor is ON, and the voltage is zero. In time period 2, I suspect I see the back emf. In time period 3 the upper transistor is switching. And in time period 4 I think it is the back EMF again, but this time negative. Due to the mosfet diode the back emf is clamped to -0.7V during time period (I think).

has anyone here done anything like this? I need some guidance on how to properly measure the BEMF.

[image]

[image]

Edit: Another method is comparing with Vbus (mentioned in one comment below):

[image]

I measured now between Vbus/2 and one of the phases, and it looks like below. I set the "ground" of the oscilloscope probe to Vbus/2. The red circle marks where the phase equals half of Vbus. So that's what I need to trigger on in the MCU?

Edit2:
It seems starting the BLDC sensorless control is more complex than I thought. What I am doing now is simply switching between commutations to get speed. But I have read now somewhere that I need to accelerate the motor at a certain rate because "The angle between the stator and rotor magnetic fields must be in 90deg±30deg.". Otherwise I won't get a correct measurement of the BEMF. Page 25,

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1913.pdf

Is this really the case? Seems to make things substantially more difficult.

[image]

Comment: I worked with a colleague while he was figuring all this stuff out. He was eventually very successful. I think 2 might be the real back emf. Maybe you can put a low pass filter in series with your oscilloscope to remove the switching hash. You will probably need that in your real circuit, too.

Comment: Use two probes in A-B mode relative to Vbus/2

Comment: Which controller are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to make the controller myself by software on a c2000 MCU from TI.